# Dynamic URL variable for SEO with Meteor

Tags: meteor, url-rewriting, seo, iron-router

I'm working on a Meteor app which uses [ms-seo package](https://atmospherejs.com/manuelschoebel/ms-seo). I was wondering if there is a way to make URLs more SEO friendly?

```
Router.route('/item/:_id', {
  name: 'item.detail',
  controller: 'ItemsController',
  action: 'detail',
  where: 'client',
  onAfterAction: function() {
    var data = this.data();
    if (data) {
    SEO.set({
      title: data.title + ' - ' + data.company + ' (' + data.city + ')',
      meta: {
        'description': data.descriptionHTML
      }
    });
  }
});
```

While this works perfect, the URL it produces is `/item/5RTxofPPn3LwifP24`, I would like to push `data.title` up in the url, so I can get `/item/i-am-a-lower-case-dash-replaced-unique-title/`

Are there packages for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a slug. So your collection will have fields like:

- _id
- title
- slug
- content

Then to make your slug you can use something like https://atmospherejs.com/yasaricli/slugify to convert your title into a slug. Basically what it does is convert a title called "Unique Shopping Cart Item" to "unique-shopping-cart-item."

Then in your router you pass the slug in as your parameter.

```
Router.route('/blog/:slug',{
    name:'blogPosts',
    waitOn: function() { return Meteor.subscribe('collection'); },
    data: function(){
        var slug = this.params.slug;
        return Collection.findOne({slug:slug});
        // this is saying search the collection's slug for the passed in parameter which we're also calling "slug"
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [slugify](https://atmospherejs.com/yasaricli/slugify) to push the `data.title` as a pretty url.